# Command in Crontab not running but can be executed directly on the terminal

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, cron

I created a cronjob on ubuntu server using the following command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And added the following line:

```
* * * * * cd /vhosts/example.com && sudo /usr/bin/docker exec -it sample-fpm /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But nothing happened. When I check on `sudo /etc/init.d/cron status`. I can see the log contains the above command.

If I run `cd /vhosts/example.com && sudo /usr/bin/docker exec -it sample-fpm /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` directly on terminal, it work fine.

**UPDATE**

I have tried directly set the cron on container but same result. And tried to do some simple thing such as `touch /tmp/test.txt` on crontab and it work fine. Not sure why the `artisan` command doesn't work on the crontab.

Comment: If you create `cron` via `sudo` you do not need second `sudo` in the command. `cron` is not very "happy" with `sudo` in commands

Comment: Why are you running a cronjob in the crontab from your main OS to put a cronjob in a containers user ? You should run the cronjob directly in the container

Comment: Something like this is what I mean. This needs to be runned in the container after running the image. Please note this codesample is made for user `application`:
`crontab -u application  -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /cron.log 2>&1"; } | crontab -u application  - `

Comment: @RomeoNinov I already tried. But same result. Thanks.

Comment: @Techno I have tried directly set on container, but same result. And I tried to do  some simple thing such as `touch /tmp/test.txt` on crontab and it work fine. Not sure why the `artisan` command doesn't work on the crontab.

Comment: Allright, so can you log into the terminal of your container directly? If so, can you switch to the user that executes your webrequests(usually www-data/nxing/apache/etc) with `su -s /bin/bash {username}` and use `crontab -e` there? Then add in the line and test it like this. I know running everything in one go can be problematic(hard to find breaking component), so splitting it up in separate steps gives you more control and insight over what's going wrong

Comment: @Techno Tried to set the `crontab` on `www-data` user inside the container. But still same result.

Comment: Can you verify, in the container, that the crond service is running? It could be the case that it isn't. You could ass this line to the dockerfile: `RUN docker-service-enable cron`

Comment: @Techno Thanks! Cron is not running inside the docker container. Solved by `service cron start`.

Comment: Perfect! Now make sure you add the cronjob to the correct user's crontab, and make sure you never ever unnecessarily use root acces ANYWERE :D

Comment: @Techno `www-data` don't have permission to run `service cron start`. So adding `RUN docker-service-enable cron` in the dockerfile and rebuild the container can solve this problem?

Comment: I can verify that enabling the cron service needs to be done as root(my literal code is `RUN  crontab -u application  -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /cron.log 2>&1"; } | crontab -u application  - ; 
USER root
RUN docker-service-enable cron`)

Comment: All the ALLCAPS words need to be first word on newline